# Xamarin binding call methods

Tags: binding, xamarin

I've created a binding project to my original project, i've added my library to the binding project. This is my code in ApiDefinition.cs:

```
public partial interface TestInterface1 
{
    [Static,Export ("sum:with:")]
    int TestAdd (int first, int second);
}
```

I added the binding as a reference to my original project, but how do i call the TestAdd() ? I find the interface in the namespace but im not sure how to use it?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what is it you're asking here, you need to put more context in your question. If you're asking how to bind a native library try Objective Sharpie

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do either.  You can't directly use a method on an interface unless it is referring to a class that implements that interface.  Have you created a class that looks something like this, "public class SomeClassName : TestInterface1"?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get hold of an instance of an object that implements TestInterface1. If you don't have such a thing you maybe want to change your interface to a class so you can instantiate an object of type TestInterface1 yourself?

```
public class TestInterface1 
{
    [Static,Export ("sum:with:")]
    int TestAdd (int first, int second);
}
```

and then use it like

```
var test = new TestInterface1();
var result = test.TestAdd(1,2);
```

Makes sense?